# Google Maps API MoveCamera vs GetCameraPosition

Tags: android, google-maps

Why I not get back the same position with GetCameraPosition() what I have set with MoveCamera() ?

I test that like this:

Set the camera:

```
...
LatLng curPos = new LatLng(48.1698934, 11.5515271);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(curPos));
Log.i("Position", setPos.toString());
...
```

Then in OnCamera Listener I read the position:

```
 @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        //The camera has stopped moving.
        CameraPosition xPos = mMap.getCameraPosition();
        Log.i("Position", xPos.toString());

    }
```

in Logcat I get this:

```
xxxxxx I/Position: lat/lng: (**48.1698934,11.5515271**)
xxxxxx I/Position: CameraPosition{target=lat/lng: (**
48.16989330826159,11.551527231931688**), zoom=3.0, tilt=0.0, bearing=0.0}
```

which definitely shows the get position is different than what I have set. Why is this difference? How would be fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the same but just rounded. Since your curPos variable coordinates are only 7 decimals you are technically not setting the exact position on the map.  The exact position would be the most a double can take, which is about 15.  When the camera gets the position it gives the most accurate number it can from a double.  Which is why the numbers are not exactly the same.
You could try adding trailing 0s to the lat and lng variables which might do the trick.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for reply but it is not a solution. I have tried. Added trailing zeros but result is totally same. LatLng setPos = new LatLng(48.169893400000000, 11.551527100000000);  -> result: LatLng setPos = new LatLng(48.169893400000000, 11.551527100000000);
Also I do not understand your "rounding" explanation....If I round figure according rounding rules then result still not good: 48.16989330826159 rounding to 7 decimals -> 48.1698933 (What I would like to get is 48.1698934  (Difference is small, but it is there)

Comment: Ehhhh what's going...? in logcat I see number: "48.16989330826159" but as I copied it to here it is changed to "48.48.169893400000000" ....
I am a bit confused.

Comment: Ahhh a copied wrong line. Logcat is showing this:
xxxxx I/Position: CameraPosition{target=lat/lng: (48.16989330826159,11.551527231931688), zoom=3.0, tilt=0.0, bearing=0.0}

Comment: Difference can better seen with these figures:

xxxxx I/Position: lat/lng: (48.0,11.0)
xxxxx I/Position: CameraPosition{target=lat/lng: (47.99999993815757,11.000000014901161), zoom=3.0, tilt=0.0, bearing=0.0}

Comment: Then if I round the got figures to 8 decimals I get 47.99999994
11.00000001 which are not equal with the original (set) numbers.